# Get total rows when using limit/offset on Google DataStore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

```
ListingStore.query().filter(ListingStore.account_id==1).fetch(10, offset=40)
```

Above is a query to return the 5th page of results from my dataset.
My problem is that I have to return the total number of rows as well, like this:

```
{
    "data": ...,
    "limit": 10,
    "offset": 40,
    "total": 1235
}
```

I can use `count()` to get the `total`, like this:

```
ListingStore.query().filter(ListingStore.account_id==1).count()
```

But that seems to take as long as the fetch() to run, causing the whole thing take twice as long.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.count()` **is** more efficient than the equivalent query, but only by some constant factor (depending on how large each entity is -- minimally so compared to a keys-only query).

The only drastic performance acceleration you can get is by **denormalizing** your data model to "redundantly" keep track of how many `ListingStore` entities you have with each `account_id`.

For the purpose, you could just introduce a new entity `ListingStoreByAccount` with the `account_id` as the id in the key, so it can be fetched very fast, and an `IntegerProperty` w/the current count.

You'll need to keep the appropriate entity updated on each creation or deletion of a `ListingStore` entity, perhaps in a transaction (with a fake key-only "parent" per `ListingStoreByAccount` as the entity group) if concurrency is otherwise a problem.

Should counter contention become a problem, reach for a high-speed sharded counter instead, e.g per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters and the example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sharded-counters-python as example code.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need the count of every `account_id` all the time, I would use [The Memcache Pattern](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache) to run the `count()` when needed, and cache the results for subsequent page queries.

Then, as Alex mentions, delete the appropriate cache entry when the `ListingStore` changes.